# Difference between a Row and its lead by 3 Rows in a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aggregation, shift

I have a CSV file which has been imported as a dataframe through the following codes:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("name of file.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)
df.show()
```

output

```
    +-----+------+-----+
    |col1 | col2 | col3|
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  A  |  2   |  4  |
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  A  |  4   |  5  | 
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  A  |  7   |  7  | 
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  A  |  3   |  8  | 
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  A  |  7   |  3  | 
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  B  |  8   |  9  |
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  B  |  10  |  10 | 
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  B  |  8   |  9  |
    +-----+------+-----+    
    |  B  |  20  |  15 |
    +-----+------+-----+
```

I want to create another `col4` which contains `col2[n+3]/col2-1` for each group in `col1` separately.

The output should be

```
   +-----+------+-----+-----+
   |col1 | col2 | col3| col4|
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    2 |   4 |  0.5|  #(3/2-1)
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    4 |   5 | 0.75| #(7/4-1)
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    7 |   7 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    3 |   8 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    7 |   3 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |    8 |   9 | 1.5 |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |   10 |  10 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |    8 |  9  |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |   20 |  15 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+
```

I know how to do this in pandas but I am not sure how to do some computation on the grouped column in PySpark.

At the moment, my PySpark version is 2.4

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In pandas is df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-3)) / df['col2'] - 1, which works. But I don't know what to do in pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Spark version is `2.2`. [lead()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead) and [Window()](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) have been used. For [reference](https://www.arundhaj.com/blog/calculate-difference-with-previous-row-in-pyspark.html).

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, col    
my_window = Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy('col1')
df = df.withColumn('col2_lead_3', lead(col('col2'),3).over(my_window))\
       .withColumn('col4',(col('col2_lead_3')/col('col2'))-1).drop('col2_lead_3')
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   B|   8|   9| 1.5|
|   B|  10|  10|null|
|   B|   8|   9|null|
|   B|  20|  15|null|
|   A|   2|   4| 0.5|
|   A|   4|   5|0.75|
|   A|   7|   7|null|
|   A|   3|   8|null|
|   A|   7|   3|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. I only have to import col as well since I got the error "col is not defined" so added this line to my codes : from pyspark.sql.functions import col

Comment: Instead of col('col1') you can also write `df.col1` or `df['col1']`. It's one and the same thing. Then you don’t have to import `Col`.